# Associating pointers to array slices in syntatically valid manner in Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I'm new to fortran. I'm trying to get a pointer to an array slice but the compiler gives the error:

```
  ptr => output_conv(i,:,:)
                      1
  Error: Syntax error in argument list at (1)
```

The relevant code is below:

```
subroutine dummyRoutine(output_conv,upperlimit)
   implicit none
   integer::i, upperlimit
   real, dimension(:,:,:), target::output_conv
   real, dimension(:,:), pointer::ptr
   do i = 1, upperlimit
      ptr => output_conv(i,:,:)
   end do
end subroutine
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there some syntax quirk I'm unaware of?

Comment: The `associate` construct is a safer alternative granted your arrays all have default lower bound 1 and you don't need access to the `allocatable` attribute. [See: Cray documentation](http://docs.cray.com/books/S-3692-52/html-S-3692-52/z1060204700pvl.html)

Comment: There is now nothing obviously wrong with the code to provoke that error.  What compiler (including version) do you use, and with what compile options?

Comment: Syntax error in ARGUMENT LIST (caps for emphasis) is a little strange ...